# Linux-to-Linux IPython kernel connection over ssh failing where Windows-to-Linux works

Tags: ssh, jupyter, ipython, spyder

I've been smoothly running a set-up where I develop using Spyder IDE on a Windows client connected to a remote IPython kernel running on a Linux server. (jupyter qtconsole works just as fine when Spyder works). I use SSH tunnel (Bitvise 3rd party in Windows, native ssh in Linux) to forward ports to my local clients.

The set-up has been working successfully with the Windows clients across two different Windows machines / OS versions / client library versions, yet trying the same with a Linux client simply fails to connect. I've used `tcpdump` on the Linux server to look at traffic going through the 5 ports used (shell, iopub, stdin, control, hb), and noticed that the Linux client sends different messages (even different sizes), and fails to connect, looping forever trying to connect. I'll paste here the first message for the shell port (seems to have most activity anyway) from the client to the server:

Windows client (the one that works):

```
0000   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 86 dd 60 0d
0010   97 bd 00 28 06 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0020   00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0030   00 00 00 00 00 01 b1 0a 13 25 93 64 45 7c 00 00
0040   00 00 a0 02 ff c4 00 30 00 00 02 04 ff c4 04 02
0050   08 0a 61 92 0f 72 00 00 00 00 01 03 03 07
```

Linux client (the one that fails):

```
0000   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 45 00
0010   00 3c 72 7c 40 00 40 06 90 5a 4a d0 d1 22 4a d0
0020   d1 22 a2 8c 13 25 fa 5a 5c b3 00 00 00 00 a0 02
0030   ff d7 38 14 00 00 02 04 ff d7 04 02 08 0a fc 08
0040   f3 b3 00 00 00 00 01 03 03 07
```